# Parse remote notifications and timezones

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, timezone

I'm looking at remote notifications with the Parse SDK and background jobs since I want my application to execute a background job (Which is pushing a notification from cloud code) at 7 am every morning.

The thing I'm confused about is that the background jobs are scheduled at 7 am UTC time, so I'm assuming that the function would execute for users at 7 am in the UTC timezone but for other users who are not in this time zone, they will receive this notification as well.

So my question is there a way to make sure users only receive the notification at 7 am based on their local timezone rather than UTC timezone which the background job is depending on?

Comment: You would need to have your app update the `installation` table to provide the current Timezone for each device and then schedule your background job to run every hour and only notify the relevant devices.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/542, you could either use node-schedule or a third-party SDK (CleverTap/PushWoosh/OneSignal)

List of alternative Push SDKs recommended by the community:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki#push-notifications-alternative-services